# Is there possible to use createQueryBuilder for insert/update? If not, what function should I use?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, insert-update, createquery

For now I succeded to create a function that retrieves data from the database using Doctrine's function createQueryBuilder.

Does anybody know if there is a similar function to insert or update the database? Or how can i use createQueryBuilder?

Comment: Check the [official documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/) and the [Query Builder docs](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html).

Comment: You, dude, need to take a depth look to Symfony2, Doctrine and so on ....

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Doctrine 2 ORM does not support `INSERT` via [DQL](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html) or the [DQL query builder](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html). For a complete syntax, check [the EBNF of DQL](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#ebnf).

To handle inserts in ORM, you always manually instantiate an entity and persist it with the entity manager:

```
$user = new \My\Entity\User();

$entityManager->persist($user);
$entityManager->flush();
```

You can only handle `SELECT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` via DQL in Doctrine ORM:

- Select:

  ```
  SELECT u FROM My\Entity\User u WHERE u.id = :userId
  ```
- Update:

  ```
  UPDATE My\Entity\User u SET u.status = 'banned' WHERE u.id = :userId
  ```
- Delete

  ```
  DELETE My\Entity\User u WHERE u.id = :userId
  ```

You can handle these operations with the QueryBuilder as well:

- Select:

```
    $queryBuilder = $entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
    $queryBuilder
        ->select('u')
        ->from('My\Entity\User', 'u')
        ->where($queryBuilder->expr()->eq('u.id', ':userId'));
```

- Delete:

```
    $queryBuilder = $entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
    $queryBuilder
        ->delete('My\Entity\User', 'u')
        ->where($queryBuilder->expr()->eq('u.id', ':userId'));
```

- Update:

```
    $queryBuilder = $entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
    $queryBuilder
        ->update('My\Entity\User', 'u')
        ->set('u.status', 'banned')
        ->where($queryBuilder->expr()->eq('u.id', ':userId'));
```

Comment: How can I execute update and insert in the same transaction? I have to use native sql query instead?

Comment: see `$entityManager->transactional()`

Comment: It seems like Doctrine DBAL supports *insert* queries from version 2.5 (?) on: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#building-a-query

Comment: @Icarus yes, but ORM doesn't.

Comment: @Icarus its dbal not ORM.

Answer (score 9):

Another option you have instead using a QueryBuilder, is using Doctrine DBAL prepare and execute functions. Probably is not as flexible as use QueryBuilder, but for do INSERTs in some situations could be useful.

The way to use is getting the Database Connection from the Entity Manager.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table (field1, field2) VALUES ('foo', 'var')";
$stmt = $em->getConnection()->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(':invoice', $invoiceId);
$result = $stmt->execute();
```

Comment: there's a reason why the ORM does not allow this. The idea is to always go through the various listeners, the computed commit order and the DBAL types conversion.

Comment: @Ocramius there is also reasons why you need this, for example inserting logs without entering ORM's lifecycle callbacks

Answer (score 9):

If you use DBAL queryBuilder, it is possible to insert.

```
$qb = $connection->createQueryBuilder();
```

To insert with the queryBuilder it is like this :

```
$qb->insert('MuBundle:MyClass', 'momc')
   ->values (array(
       'property1 (id for example)' => '?'
       'property2 (name for exmaple)' => '?'
   ))
   ->setParameter(0, $id)
   ->setparameter(1, $name)
```

Answer (score 0):

using  QueryBuilder to insert data is not possible unless your are willing to write the DQL or SQL. If you are looking for a way to simply insert data to your database table, you have to first of all make sure the data is loaded into an Entity class for the table in which you want to insert your data. For example `$em->persist($entity);`