# Insert record with Doctrine Query Builder

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, dbal

I want to use Doctrine's DBAL Query Builder to insert record into database.

I've found that this in fact is possible in the latest documentation via `insert` method:
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#building-a-query

However, I have the latest version of DBAL installed via Composer and it has no such methods.

Why is that?

What are my alternatives?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Missing insert() method on Doctrine DBAL Query Builder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25437816/missing-insert-method-on-doctrine-dbal-query-builder)

Comment: What exact version are you using? Also see the question linked above.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you installed the latest stable (2.4.2) and this [version](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/v2.4.2/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Query/QueryBuilder.php) contains no `insert` method in the QueryBuilder.

If you check the same [file](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Query/QueryBuilder.php#L585) on the master branch this contains the `insert` method

I think there is something wrong with the documentation as I can't find anywhere how to view the documentation of the latest stable ...