# symfony2: inserting data using eventListener

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.3

I'm using symfony 2.3. I'm trying to generate an Invoice for every commercial every end of a month. I implemented a Listener called *InvoiceListener* in order to that. The problem is *updateInvoice()* function doesn't insert the data into invoice table. The system doesn't render errors. The doctrine debuger in displaying the query correctly.
[image]
**InvoiceListener.php**

```
class InvoiceListener {

  private $em;

  public function __construct(\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager $em) {
      $this->em = $em;
  }

  public function process(GetResponseEvent $event) {

      $expire = '2012-01-01';
      $current_month = date("m");
      $current_year = date("y");
      if (date("d") == 1) {
          echo 'first day';
          $this->updateStatus($current_month, $current_year);
          $this->updateInvoice();
      } else {
          echo 'not first day';
          $users = $this->findByRole('ROLE_COMMERCIAL');
          // update invoice
          $this->updateInvoice($users);
      }
  }

  public function updateStatus($current_month, $current_year) {
      $queryBuilder = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();
      $queryBuilder
              ->update('Biginfo\UserBundle\Entity\User', 'u')
              ->set('u.nbrBusiness', 1)
              ->set('u.month', $current_month)
              ->set('u.year', $current_year);
      return $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();
  }

  public function updateInvoice($users) {
      $queryBuilder = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();
      foreach ($users as $user) {
          $queryBuilder
                  ->update('Biginfo\AdminBundle\Entity\Invoice', 'c')
                  ->set('c.commercial', $user->getId())
                  ->set('c.month', $user->getMonth())
                  ->set('c.year', $user->getYear())
                  ->set('c.nbrBusiness', $user->getNbrBusiness());
      }
      return $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();
  }

  /**
   * @param string $role
   *
   * @return array
   */
  public function findByRole($role) {
      $qb = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();
      $qb->select('u')
              ->from('Biginfo\UserBundle\Entity\User', 'u')
              ->where('u.roles LIKE :roles')
              ->setParameter('roles', '%"' . $role . '"%');

      return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
  }

}
```

Comment: "_... I'm trying to generate an Invoice for every commercial every end of a month ..._" - Sound like you need a [Console Command](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/console_command.html) instead and call it with a cronjob.

Comment: I agree with @BentCoder. Using a listener for this is an overkill imho.

Comment: agree too with @BentCoder  , should use  console

Comment: @BentCoder do you have a tutorial about conjobs. I'm a newbie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I am missing something, your code will only **update the same record** over and over again, I don't think that's what you want. To generate new invoices, you should change it like this:

```
public function updateInvoice($users) {
    $queryBuilder = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();
    $queryBuilder->insert('Biginfo\AdminBundle\Entity\Invoice', 'c');
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        $queryBuilder->values(array(
            'c.commercial' => $user->getId(),
            'c.month' => $user->getMonth(),
            'c.year'=> $user->getYear(),
            'c.nbrBusiness' => $user->getNbrBusiness()
        ))
    }
    return $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

P.S. you should also use placeholders, see http://doctrine-dbal.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#binding-parameters-to-placeholders

## EDIT: "insert" command

The "insert" command [has been added in Doctrine 2.5.0 BETA 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25437816/missing-insert-method-on-doctrine-dbal-query-builder), so it may not be available in Symfony 2.3. An alternative to that is to use plain SQL, e.g.

```
public function updateInvoice($users) {
    $connection = $this->container->get('doctrine.dbal.default_connection');    
    $values = array();
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        $values[] = "(
            '" . $user->getId() . "',
            '" . $user->getMonth() . "',
            '" . $user->getYear() . "',
            '" . $user->getNbrBusiness() . "'
            )";
    }
    $sql = "INSERT INTO invoice (`commercial`, `month`, `year`, `nbrBusiness`) VALUES " . implode("," , $values);
    $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
    $statement->execute();
}
```

Comment: Call to undefined method Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder::insert()

Comment: Edited my answer to account for that