# symfony repository logic functions

Tags: php, symfony, repository

Hello i saw a lot of tutorials and still dont know how can i make custom functions in my already done repository.

this is content of my CommentController:

```
public function newAction(Request $request, $productId)
{
    $comment = new Comment();
    $form = $this->formFactory->create(CommentForm::class, $comment);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

        $em = $this->get('doctrine')->getManager();
        /** @var Product $product */
        $product = $em->getRepository(Product::class)->find($productId);

        $comment->setAuthor($this->tokenStorsge->getToken()->getUser());
        $comment->setProduct($product);
        $comment->setContent($form->get('content')->getData());

        $this->em->persist($comment);
        $this->em->flush();

    }

    return $this->render(':form:comment.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

and i just want to make some function to make controller more beautiful any ideas? if you give me and example how can i insert my data into database via custom repository function. I know how to make custom query thats all. Every help/idea is very helpfull!

Comment: Your action is about as beautiful as one would want it. Persistence is already decoupled, repository hide the complexity of queries, your looking good, IMO. :)

Comment: Yes i would give queries that is not problem i guess, but what about that setters? Its not nice, does not it?

Comment: I think it depends on who you ask. Die hard DDD fans might want that tucked away. Some might advocate passing all parameters at construction. I like the way Symfony handles this - it's clear - easy to update - easy to test - I have no issues with this approach personally.

Comment: Okey i just thought it should look better if somebody help me make custom function and i just call something like `$this->saveData(parameters);` and everything is done

Comment: If your Controller inherits the base Symfony Controller (eg. `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller`), you can simply do `$this->getUser()` instead of going through the tokenStorage - everything else seems fine.

Comment: Okey guys, thanks:)

Comment: If you use Symfony 3.3 you can inject services in your controller actions with type-hinting. See https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html

Answer (score 1):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15619054/is-there-possible-to-use-createquerybuilder-for-insert-update-if-not-what-func)

> Doctrine 2 ORM does not support `INSERT` via [DQL](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html) or the [DQL query builder](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html). For a complete syntax, check [the EBNF of DQL](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#ebnf).

You can add more abstractions if you want your controller to look slightly more beautiful, off the top of my head (effective in Symfony 2.8):

`BaseController.php`:

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

abstract class BaseController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @return ProductRepository
     */
    protected function getProductRepo()
    {
        return $this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager')->getRepository(Product::class);
    }
}
```

`CommentController.php`:
Use native controller functions to create a form and get the currently logged in user. And if you are not intend to add more complex logic between `$form->isSubmitted()` and `$form->isValid()` use just `$form->isValid()`

```
class CommentController extends BaseController
{
    public function newAction(Request $request, $productId)
    {
        $comment = new Comment();

        $form = $this->createForm(CommentForm::class, $comment);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            /** @var Product $product */
            $product = $this->getProductRepo()->find($productId);

            $comment->setAuthor($this->getUser());
            $comment->setProduct($product);
            $comment->setContent($form->get('content')->getData());

            $this->em->persist($comment);
            $this->em->flush();

        }

        return $this->render(':form:comment.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
}
```